# Cassandra on dual core machine

Tags: c#, cassandra

Currently I'm working on a machine with 2 cores and 4 gb ram. I made a simple C# program that bulk inserts data into a table (1 million rows). Whenever I run the code it only inserts about 250.000 rows into the table.

I know this is a hardware problem, because when I use this code on a different machine with 8 cores and 16 gb ram it works totally fine and it inserts the million rows without a problem.

I do not get any error from Cassandra nor from C# why it does not insert them all.

Can I do something (either in C# code) or in Cassandra settings (maybe something like increasing the heap space or allocate more ram) so Cassandra will not just stop inserting the rows, but actually finish with the inserts?

Don't know if it is any use but here is the (simple) code I'm using to insert Data into my Cassandra database:

```
private void bt_cluster_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Connect(); //Cluster.Builder and connecting to a cluster.
        List<Meter> meterList = fillList(); // filling a list with meter ojects
        var statement = session.Prepare("insert into meters (ID, ConnectionMeterID, ConnectionMeterRevision, PeriodStart, PeriodEnd, Volume1, Volume2, Volume3, Volume4, Volume5, Volume6, Volume7, Volume8, DataTypeID, FileID, Remarks, QualityScore, LocationID, Removed) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (Meter m in meterList)
        {

            var bind = statement.Bind(m.ID, m.ConnectionMeterID, m.ConnectionMeterRevision, m.date1, m.date2, m.volume1, m.volume2, m.volume3, m.volume4, m.volume5, m.volume6, m.volume7, m.volume8, m.DataTypeID, m.FileID, m.Remarks, m.QualityScore, m.LocationID, m.Removed);
            var resultSetFuture = session.ExecuteAsync(bind);
            tasks.Add(resultSetFuture);
        }
        CloseConnection();//shutdown the cluster
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are not waiting for the async tasks to finish before you close the connection.

use `Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());` before closing the connection.

UPDATE:
For such a big chunk of work, WaitAll will not work.
use:

```
foreach(var task in tasks)
{
    task.Wait();
}
```

or `Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();`

In an async method you would just use:

`await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`